# Load The Same Page But Prevent Refreshing Content

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I don't what's wrong with the code I have printed below :

```
window.top.location = window.top.location;
```

I thought it'll just load the same page in the same window, but it's actually refreshing the page.

What could be done to prevent the refresh? All I want is the page to load again in the same window but no refresh (to prevent server resources)?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "the page", because it's clearly different from what I think of when I think of a refresh. What, specifically, is loading on refresh that you don't want to?

Comment: `window.location` will effect a page reload. Check on using `ajax` to load the contents of your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should design your application in order to do that - updating `window.location` will issue a full page reload.

Check client-side templating or [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com) either.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always use cookies, to persist data http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm

But can I ask about the use-case for that? If you just want to upload part of your page, you should use ajax for that, because updating the whole page will be both slow and a waste of bandwidth for your server.

EDIT: Some good tutorial on [Getting started with AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)